# pydub no ffprobe found

Tags: python-3.x, ffmpeg, py2app, pydub

I have an app for MacOS that is compiled with `py2app`. The app uses the `pydub` module and the latter uses ffmpeg family package.

The problem is that once I compile the app and move it to a different OS, the `subprocess` call from `pydub` fails to find any of the `ffmpeg` packages even though they are installed in `/usr/local/bin`.

If I launch the app from terminal `./Nameapp.app/Contents/MacOs/Nameapp` then it runs no problem, but if I launch it with double click then `pydub` complains not finding the packages and the app hangs where `ffmpeg/ffprobe` should do the work.

I can see that `pydub` searches in the `/usr/local/bin` only if launched from terminal, otherwise no. If I add `/usr/local/bin` to `PATH`, `pydub` doesnt complain anymore that it doesnt find ffmpeg/ffprobe, but it still gives me an error for both ffmpeg and ffprobe:  `[Errno 2] No such file or directory:`.

If I hardcode the path `pydub.AudioSegment.converter = "/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg"`, the app gives me only ffprobe error `[Errno 2] No such file or directory:'ffprobe': 'ffprobe'`.

On some other posts i've seen `pydub.AudioSegment.ffprobe = "/path/to/ffprobe"` but it doesnt seem to work in my case?

So my two questions are:

How to hardcode the ffprobe path in pydub?
How to solve this without hardcoding path?

Comment: I had a similar experience in the past and I was able to solve by calling the `subprocess` with `['/bin/bash', '-i', '-c', name]`. but I wouldn't want to do this here

Answer (score 0):

for some reason it works when changing the shell to zsh... switching back to bash no. not really happy with this solution but it's something